Postgres JDBC without database name
I want to write a program that connects to a PostgreSQL server for the purpose of creating a new database (i.e., its first statement will be CREATE DATABASE). If you use a JDBC URL with no database name (e.g., jdbc:postgresql://localhost), Postgres attempts to connect to a database named after the user, and fails if that database doesn't exist. How can I use JDBC to connect to the server but no particular database?

You must use a database name. In case of a fresh cluster without any user defined databases, you use the default database postgres.

I think that technically there is no guarantee that there will be a database named postgres. But I also suspect that there is no better solution, so please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

@DanR. It is possible and allowed to drop the postgres database, but whoever does that will find that a lot of tools won't work well any more.

PostgreSQL by default has a database called postgres whose express porpose it is to receive connections that then create or drop databases. So you should use that.
PostgreSQL has two more default databases, template0 and template1. The former does not accept connections, but the latter does. In very old PostgreSQL versions, before postgres was invented, template1 was used as the database to connect to in order to create a database. The problem with that was that CREATE DATABASE fails if somebody else is connected to template1, so there was a race condition for the concurrent execution of töols like createdb.
To play it safe, you could do what the PostgreSQL utility programs do: connect to postgres, and if that fails, connect to template1. Anybody who drops both of these database has seriously mutilated their database cluster and can safely be discounted.
